# iptables DROP counters

Tags: linux, iptables, ddos

I've discovered strange connections to my web server from 10 different IP addresses with same subnet `46.229.168.0/23`.

This subnet belongs to a hosting provider and hardly represent real users.

After that, I've blocked them through iptables.

I'm trying to understand if I'm being DDOS attacked?

I ran:

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

and got the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2141K packets, 1607M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

 158K 9369K DROP       tcp  --  *      *       46.229.168.0/23      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
```

9369K - packages were dropped for 24 hours.

Is it enough to say that it's a DDOS attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too small to be DDoS by bandwidth, but that doesn't in itself mean it's not trying to exploit something in your web server, either for application-layer DoS such as the Range header vulnerability, or for spam.

You don't say what is 'strange' about the connections.  Hard-to-explain moderate volume traffic can mean you are being co-opted into a reflection attack and the DRDoS victim is elsewhere, usually indicated by the spoofed IP address (layer 3 DRDoS) or URL (layer 7).  For example if you see lots of half-open `SYN_RECV` connections, then ensure tcp_syncookies is turned on.  A layer 7 DRDoS is something like `xmlrpc.php` calls in WordPress.

However, what you do give is the IP range, and that is related to an aggressive bot called [SEMrushBot](https://www.semrush.com/bot/) as you may be able to see from User-Agent in the logs.  It seems to be a kind of tertiary service that is of no value to you or your visitors, so may be worth blocking in `robots.txt` as it suggests.

```
User-agent: SemrushBot
Disallow: / 
User-agent: SemrushBot-SA
Disallow: /
```

or just firewall the suspicious ranges.

Answer (score 0):

It's around 100rps. Don't looks like real DDoS. May be someone tries to make DDoS against your server, but it looks ridiculous.